# How to change a pointed value and increment the pointer at the same time

Tags: c, pointers

```
char foo[] = "something";
char *p = foo;
```

Is there a way to change the value pointed and increment the pointer to the next element using only one ;?

I mean, make the effect of these 2 lines below in a single statement?

```
 *p = 'S';
 p++;
```

Comment: Although doing as you intend to might look fancy, it does not enhance readability. There are few situtations I'd accept this in a code review.

Comment: `*p = 'S'; p++;` is already canonical code. Any change of it will make the program less readable and potentially also less safe, since mixing ++ with other operators is bad and dangerous practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want

```
*p++ = 'S'; // as good as -->   *(p++) = 'S';
```

[Sample run](http://ideone.com/WFIV4w).

Comment: Like @Lundin said below, I don't think the parentheses are idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job :

```
*p++ = 'S';
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, if you would like to increment first and get the next value:

```
*++p = 'o';
```

As you can see among all the answers, you have a choice, to either

**(1) dereference, then increment pointer:**

```
*p++ = 'S';
```

or 
**(2) increment pointer, then dereference:**

```
*++p = 'o';
```

Both can be used as needed as loop increments, tests, and in varying other contexts.

Comment: As we can tell from the parenthesis on the first line, this code is not readable. The parenthesis is actually completely superfluous, but since you managed to confuse yourself by obfuscating the code, you put the parenthesis there anyway. So all you managed was to write code which you don't know how it works. A much better way to write the same code is `p++; p = 'o';`

Comment: I hate it when that happens. Updated to remove superfluous obfuscation.

Comment: My point was that this whole answer, together with the others, is superfluous obfuscation of already perfect code.

Answer (score 1):

```
 *p = 'S';
 p++;
```

This is already optimal code. You cannot enhance the readability, safety, performance or maintainability of this code by changing it.

If you insist to change it, for no sane reason, then sure you can do it:

```
??=define BORK ;
??=define BOINK *
??=define SPLURK ++
??=define SPROING =

BOINK p SPROING 'S' BORK p SPLURK BORK
```

This is really bad code. I'm sure others are also happy to provide more such examples of code which is much worse than what you already had.